# Have error with OAuthController when I copied and paste the code as Autodesk Forge tutorial

Tags: c#

The coding in C# showing error as below:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0103  The name 'OAuthController' does not exist in the current context

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5a4E.png)

Hopefully, group help me solve this issue. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Before you ask a question make sure to read through [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Instead of attaching an image please provide code in text format! For your question: It seems like `OAuthController` does not exist in your context. Where do you retrieve `OAuthController` from?

Comment: I just start learning Autodesk Forge. The code was copied from Autodesk tutorial. Below is the code in text format. Thanks for your help. Here is my code in text format.  namespace ForgeSample.Controllers
{
    public class OSSController : ApiController
    {
        public string ClientId { get { return OAuthController.GetAppSetting("FORGE_CLIENT_ID").ToLower(); } }

        /// <summary>
        /// Return list of buckets (id=#) or list of objects (id=bucketKey)
        /// </summary>
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/forge/oss/buckets")]....

Comment: Hi @Hoa Le, you can edit your original post and add the code there instead. Make sure to use `` or CTRL + K to make the code formatted in your text for easier readability! Did you see the answer below? Did that help you? If so you can upvote it and mark it as an answer!

Comment: Hi, I have solved my issue. Thanks

Comment: Hi again @Hoa Le, if you solved your problem, please post an answer and mark it as the solution in order to help others :)

Answer (score 0):

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;
```

One of these imports should resolve the error.